# sql query sum bringing back different results

Tags: sql

I have the following two queries below, the Total is coming back different, but I am adding the sums in each of the query the same way.  Why is the total coming back different?

```
    select [Total Children] = (SUM(demo.NumberOfPreschoolers) + SUM(demo.NumberOfToddlers) + SUM(demo.NumberOfInfants)),
County = co.Description
from ClassroomDemographics as demo
inner join Classrooms as c on demo.Classroom_Id = c.Id
inner join Sites as s on c.Site_Id = s.Id
inner join Profiles as p on s.Profile_Id = p.Id
inner join Dictionary.Counties as co on p.County_Id = co.Id
where co.Description = 'MyCounty'
Group By co.Description


select [Number Of DLL Children] = SUM(cd.NumberOfLanguageSpeakers),
[Total Children] = (SUM(demo.NumberOfPreschoolers) + SUM(demo.NumberOfToddlers) + SUM(demo.NumberOfInfants)),
County = co.Description
from ClassroomDLL as cd
inner join Classrooms as c on cd.Classroom_Id = c.Id
inner join Sites as s on c.Site_Id = s.Id
inner join Profiles as p on s.Profile_Id = p.Id
inner join Dictionary.Counties as co on p.County_Id = co.Id
inner join ClassroomDemographics as demo on c.Id = demo.Classroom_Id
where co.Description = 'MyCounty'
Group by co.Description
```

Comment: Notice that the second query has an extra inner join. Is the number of rows in both resultsets equal?

Comment: there is only one row in each result set, the second query has three columns of info, the first query only has two columns of info.  The extra inner join is supposed to be there for the second query because I need the extra column of info.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify, have you tried running raw selects (without the aggregates) on both queries and verified that the resultsets have the same number of records. Basically just asking what @Brandon Moretz answered below.

Comment: @cdlong Actually, yeah. My answer probably is betters suited as a comment. It just seems like this is the cause of his issue.

Comment: I think you're right, I'm just trying to figure out how to bring back all three columns of data with the correct data.....Maybe I need to separate the queries?

Comment: @Brandon Moretz agreed. Think yours is well stated as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick glance over the two querties, I would presume that:

```
inner join ClassroomDemographics as demo on c.Id = demo.Classroom_Id
```

in the second query is excluding results that are in the first query, therefor the aggregated values will be different.

Comment: That join is in both queries (albeit in different places and the join is constructed in the opposit way so it makes it difficult to compare the two).  I think the join on `ClassroomDLL` in the second query is actually the one excluding results.

Answer (score 0):

Your join to the `Classrooms` table is joining with an extra table in the 2nd query.

Query 1:

```
from ClassroomDemographics as demo
inner join Classrooms as c on demo.Classroom_Id = c.Id
```

Query 2:

```
from ClassroomDLL as cd
inner join Classrooms as c on cd.Classroom_Id = c.Id
...
inner join ClassroomDemographics as demo on c.Id = demo.Classroom_Id
```

My bet is that the `ClassroomDLL` table has less data in it, or has rows with a null for one of the join criteria columns, either of which could exclude rows from the results and throw your aggregate totals off.